# Meaning of multiple free variables in a traffic flow simulation using linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if the number of free variables in a general solution to a underdermined system can tell me something?
I have this traffic flow example and it has 9 intersections but 12 unknowns - get four free variables - but if choose a traffic number to one of them ,all the other 11 take are bound by that, right  - its not like I can choose random number to all four and just the other eight are bound by my chose?
I.e. in my case x12,x11,10, and x11 are free but if I choose 150 cars driving on x12 - x11,x10 and x8 are bound by that?

This is my row echelon form:

```
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0    -1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0    -1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0    -1     0     1    -1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0    -1     0     1    -1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0    -1     1    -1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0    -1     1    -1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    -1     1    -1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: The number of free variables is the dimension of your solution space. So if you have 4 free variables, that means the solution space is 4-dimensional. Choosing a value in one of those dimensions won't affect what values are possible in the other three, for the same reason that specifying an x coordinate doesn't inherently affect what values the y coordinate could take in a 2-dimensional setting.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is as having a "basic" solution $x$ and a family of *all* solutions $x+N$ s.t. $x\perp N$, where $N$ is the $k$-dimensional nullspace of your matrix. It just means that your data has nothing to say about the vectors in $N$. $x$ is the "unavoidable" part of the solution that is common to all solutions.

If you were to solve this more generally using the pseudo-inverse (i.e.,
Moore-Penrose inverse), which also allows for over-determination, you would get a solution that doesn't touch the nullspace $N$.